# What distribution should I use?

Tags: probability, statistics

Being really bad in Statistics, need some help here. The problem is : We draw a sample of 20 laptops from a population of 1000 Laptops (serial numbers from 9000-9999). a. What distribution should i use for the serial number selected? b. What is the probability a randomly selected will be one of the last 200 to be produced. c. What is the probability the first 2 are from the last 100 to be manufactured. ** The purpose of sampling is to check the quality of the laptops, thus there are two outcomes: faulty or not-faulty.

Comment: What distributions do you already know of?

Comment: I am a returning student to uni, thus i can't be sure what i'm supposed to know. I believe because the sample is small, i should go with binomial. b. the probability is 0.2 c. the prob is 0.1 * 0.1. Is it that simple? or im missing something there?

Comment: 'What distribution should i use for the serial number selected?' - do you mean for the serial numbers of the sampled laptops?

Comment: You should use [the hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: I have edited my question. I assume that since we want to check the  faulty laptops, the question refers to that fact given the sample. Hypergeometric was my initial thought, but the sample is small (<5%)

Comment: a) is still unclear - if you sample 20 laptops from 1000 without replacement what sort of distribution can their serial numbers follow?

Comment: First of all thanks for the contribution here. Second of all, i stated the question as it was given to me- i know it is unclear. What i am assuming again is that since we are supposed later to check for the faulty laptops, and since we have a sample of 20 randomly chosen the question refers to "what is the distribution of the faulty laptops of the sample given"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: I think we are supposed to assume all the serial numbers are equally likely to be selected.  Suppose you select just one serial number.  Then it is a number from 9000 to 9999, all of which are equally likely.  Can you give that distribution a name?

Comment: Oh, it is just a uniform distribution, right?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, seems like i really need to refresh the basics in Statistics.